# How to make a anchor tag clickable which is inside paragraph tag?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing

Below is my string

```
String txtLink = "<p>Apply directly in our <a 
href=\"https://theorem.applytojob.com/apply/TyJy6YCsOs/Experienced- 
Backend-Engineer-Ruby?source=GitHub+Jobs\">careers page</a></p>";
```

I need the anchor tag to be clickable in Android. What I have tried so far is

```
txtJobLink.setText(""+Html.fromHtml(txtLink));
txtJobLink.setMovementMethod(BetterLinkMovementMethod.newInstance());
BetterLinkMovementMethod.linkify(Linkify.ALL,txtJobLink);
BetterLinkMovementMethod.linkifyHtml(txtJobLink);
txtJobLink.setLinksClickable(true);
```

Comment: Try putting the link inside a single apostrophe.

Comment: Its coming from API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added added `autoLink` and `linksClickable` properties in `TextView` in your xml file then please remove it.

And Change your Activity code like:

```
String txtLink = "<p>Apply directly in our <a href=\"https://theorem.applytojob.com/apply/TyJy6YCsOs/Experienced-Backend-Engineer-Ruby?source=GitHub+Jobs\">careers page</a></p>";

TextView txtJobLink = findViewById(R.id.txtJobLink);
txtJobLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    txtJobLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(txtLink, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    txtJobLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(txtLink));
}
```

So now your layout will be like:

[image]

When you will click on "careers page", it will open associated url in web browser.